# AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate: Not playing video

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, video, avfoundation

I'm trying to do a simple implementation of AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate on OSX/iOS as a sort of sanity check before continuing to implement a more complex version. I figured I would start by just making it load the full video file in one big read. To my surprise I haven't been able to get this to work.

Here's my code:

```
- (BOOL) resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(nonnull AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest
{
   NSString* path = @"/Users/andrew/Projects/work/videotextureplugin-streaming/unityProject/Assets/StreamingAssets/BigBuckBunny_640x360.m4v";

   AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest* dataRequest = loadingRequest.dataRequest;
   AVAssetResourceLoadingContentInformationRequest* contentRequest = loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest;

   // handle content request
   if (contentRequest)
   {
      NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
      unsigned long long fileSize = [attributes fileSize]; // in bytes

      NSLog(@"File Size: %llu", fileSize);

      contentRequest.contentType = @"com.apple.m4v-video";
      contentRequest.contentLength = fileSize;
      contentRequest.byteRangeAccessSupported = NO;
   }

   // handle data request
   if (dataRequest)
   {
      NSFileHandle* file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
      NSData* requestedData = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
      NSLog(@"Requested data length: %lu", (unsigned long)[requestedData length]);

      [loadingRequest.dataRequest respondWithData:requestedData];
      [loadingRequest finishLoading];
   }

   return YES;
}
```

The file size and data length values are correct when they print. It just says "AVPlayer ready to play but has zero video tracks" in the log. I've tried a few different video files, as well as various contentType settings with no luck. All of the files I've tested work fine if I open them via a URL like "file:///" followed by the same path used above.

Thanks in advance for any assistance or advice on debugging this.